# Firestore: Unable to fetch nested documents. Why?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a Vue (with Vuex) app, with a firebase/firestore backend, and I'm having trouble with fetching documents referenced by other documents. Specifically, I have a `recipes` collection (together with `users` and `comments` collections as seen in the linked photo) collection, with each contained document having, among others, `addedBy` and `comments` fields. Both are `id` strings (the comments field being an array of `id`s) of the respective documents referenced. Now, I'm not sure if this is the best way of going about it, but coming from a MongoDB background, I thought it'd be possible fetch the details of these fields like we do with MongoDB.

I have had a couple of tries but nothing seems to work. An example of this is seen in the code snippets below.

**Main Recipe Component/Container** (I query the DB for a specific recipe document)

```
<template>
  <div class="recipe-detail">
    <loader v-if="isLoading" message="Loading Recipe" size="huge" />
    <div v-else-if="!recipe" class="no-recipe">
      No such recipe in DB
    </div>
    <div v-else class="comments-and-similar">
      <div class="comments">
        <h3 class="comments-title">Comments</h3>
        <comment-form />
        <comment-list :comment-list="recipe.comments" />
      </div>
      <div class="similar-recipes">
        <similar-recipes />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

import Loader from "@/components/shared/Loader";
import PostedBy from "@/components/recipes/detail/PostedBy";
import CommentForm from "@/components/forms/CommentForm";
import CommentList from "@/components/recipes/detail/CommentList";

export default {
  name: "recipe-detail",
  components: {
    Loader,
    PostedBy,
    CommentForm,
    CommentList,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      recipeId: this.$route.params.recipeId,
      fullPath: this.$route.fullPath
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isLoading"]),
    ...mapGetters({ recipe: "recipes/recipe" }),
  },
  watch: {
    "$route.params.recipeId"(id) {
      this.recipeId = id;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({ getRecipeById: "recipes/getRecipeById" })
  },
  created() {
    if (!this.recipe || this.recipe.id !== this.recipeId) {
      this.getRecipeById(this.recipeId);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

**Comment List Component** (Here, I receive the comment id list via props)

```
<template>
  <section class="comments">
    <div v-if="commentList.length === 0">Be the first to comment on recipe</div>
    <template v-else v-for="comment in commentList">
      <comment :comment-id="comment" :key="comment" />
    </template>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import Comment from "./Comment";

export default {
  name: "comment-list",
  components: {
    Comment
  },
  props: {
    commentList: {
      type: Array,
      required: true
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

</style>
```

**Comment Component**

```
<template>
  <article>
    <div v-if="isLoading">Loading comment...</div>
    <div v-else>{{ JSON.stringify(comment) }}</div>
  </article>
</template>

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapActions } from "vuex";

export default {
  name: "comment",
  props: {
    commentId: {
      type: String,
      required: true
    }
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters(["isLoading"]),
    ...mapGetters({ comment: "recipes/comment" })
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({ getCommentById: "recipes/getCommentById" })
  },
  created() {
    this.getCommentById(this.commentId);
  }
};
</script>
```

Now, the `Comment` component is where I'm having trouble. I get each individual comment id and use it to query the DB, specifically the `comments` collection. I actually get the comment detail body from the DB, this query wont stop and results in an infinite loop. I have to comment out the method inside `created` life-cycle for it to stop. I tried the same approach for the addedBy field to query for the user and got the same issue. So, what I'm I doing wrong.

**DB structure**
[image]

**PS**: I did not feel the need to include the Vuex methods (actions) in order to reduce verbosity. They work just fine sending the corresponding queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're sharing an `isLoading` flag between all your components.

I believe what is happening is this:

1. You try to load a comment and `isLoading` is set to `true`.
2. The component `recipe-detail` re-renders to show the `Loading Recipe` message. Note that this will destroy the `comment-list`.
3. When the comment finishes loading `isLoading` will be set back to `false`.
4. `recipe-details` will re-render again, this time showing the `comment-list`. This will create a new set of `comment` components, each of which will try to load their data again. This jumps us back to step 1.

On an unrelated note, it looks like your `comment` component is relying on a single comment being held in the store. This might be fine when there's only one comment but when there are multiple comments they'll all load at the same time and only one of them will ultimately end up in the store.

Comment: You are correct in your assumption. The recipe-detail component does re-render for instance when a user adds a new comment, which is a behavior I do not want for obvious reasons. Was planning on looking into it right after I found a solution to the current issue.

Comment: @CollinsOrlando I'm unclear from your comment whether you've understood my answer. The shared `isLoading` flag is what is causing your current issue.

Comment: Oh, I might have misread/misunderstood your comment. Regardless, I found another solution, but your suggestion re: the isLoading flag causing other issues other than the one is still invaluable. Thanks for the help and I will accept your answer. Cheers!